# Insert a row based on the name of the value

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,4,5),
                   unique=c("axc","cgf","hdg","kgh"),
                   test1=c("yes","yes","no","yes"),
                   test2=c("dead","alive","alive","dead"),
                   test3=c("LA","NY","MD","KY"))
```

I want to insert a new row

```
new_row <- data.frame(
  ID = "3",
  unique="lpq",
  test2= "alive")
```

So that the new dataframe looks as follows

```
data2 <-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   unique=c("axc","cgf","lpq","hdg","kgh"),
                   test1=c("yes","yes","","no","yes"),
                   test2=c("dead","alive","alive","alive","dead"),
                   test3=c("LA","NY","","MD","KY"))
```

We see that the new row gets inserted and leaves the unspecified columns empty while filling the values in the code.

From the solutions online, I am able to do this using integer value of the row. The problem is that I want to accomplish this using the unique column. For instance, instead of telling R to insert the new row after ID = 2, I want to insert the new row after unique = "cgf".

Comment: Is it intentional that `data$id` (lower case) is numeric and `new_row$ID` (upper case) is character?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "telling R to insert the new row after" ... are you using a function that says exactly where to insert the new row (e.g., `add_row`), or are you assuming a post-concatenate sorting?

Comment: Sorry that was not intentional at all, my bad. Answering your second question I was looking for a function that would help me insert a new row and user LMc has kindly provided a solution. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a number of functions to turn unique = "cgf" into a row index. This answer uses `match` from base R:

```r
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  add_row(!!!mutate(new_row, id = as.numeric(ID), .keep = "unused"), .after = match("cgf", data$unique))
```

`add_row` (which is exported from the `tibble` package) takes name-value pairs (e.g., `id = 3`, `unique = "lpq"`) hence the `!!!` operator, which will unpack your data frame in this way.

I used the `mutate` verb to make some adjustments to `new_data` so they matched the column name/type in `data`. If that was just a typo in your post and the names/types match then you can simply do:

```r
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  add_row(!!!new_row, .after = match("cgf", data$unique))
```

Comment: ```which(data$unique == "cgf")``` this is more intuitive than match, at least for me. But, your solution works as intended.

Comment: I like `which` too, but (ignoring the column name) for more general purposes if there is more than one "cgf" `which` will return multiple indices and this code will not work; `match` will return the first. Also for this reason `match` is usually slightly faster for me. These are good things for the OP to consider.

Comment: *"if there is more than one "cgf" `which` will return multiple indices and this code will not work"* I actually like that. I'd rather have a code that breaks when there's something wrong than the one that works no matter what (But I was sneaky when quoting your comment, you prefaced this by saying  "for more general purposes"). Cheers. +1

Comment: Thank you LMc, your solution worked! Also thank you for everyones valuable feedback. @M, you raise a good point about the difference between "which" and "match". Definitely something to consider for multiple instances